# WSclock page replacement algorithm and clock tick

Tags: algorithm, memory-management, paging

Reading [this](https://cs.nyu.edu/courses/spring02/V22.0202-002/wsclock.html) , i came across the term "Clock tick".

In this case, what is this clock tick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clock tick is an [interrup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt) sent by the hardware internal clock every X cycles (or X nano seconds).

This is used a reliable timer that stops you from whatever you are doing every constant period.

Comment: This X cycles, is programmer defined, right? In addition, why is this interrupt necessary? Is this X equals to tau? (the "working set factor")?